# Why does Github 2FA recovery codes fail?

Tags: github, authentication

I am officially blocked with 2FA! I cannot login to my Github account while I was able to do it before using one of the recovery codes. I changed my phone and the authentication app doesn't work on the new one. I used one of the codes before to login and it was successful but now none of the codes are working. I also don't have a recovery token. Does anyone have any idea what to do at this point?

Comment: I face the same issue, all my recovery codes don't work anymore @@

Comment: There is now (Oct. 2022) an [Improved account recovery flow in case of a lost 2FA device](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74199728/6309).

Answer (score 3):

Oct. 2022: see also "[How to recover github password without using 2FA credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74199728/6309https://stackoverflow.com/a/74199728/6309)".

---

Apr. 2019: If none of the methods described in "[Recovering your account if you lose your 2FA credentials](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/recovering-your-account-if-you-lose-your-2fa-credentials)" would work (like a fallback number), then you would need to:

- create a new GitHub account
- [contact GitHub support](https://github.com/contact) and see if it is possible to negotiate merging back your old account with this new one.

This situation is problematic for *private* repos, and GitHub does mention:

> For security reasons, GitHub Support may not be able to restore access to accounts with two-factor authentication enabled if you lose your two-factor authentication credentials or lose access to your account recovery methods.

Still, only the support can tell you definitively what is possible in your case.

The [OP Rubbic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3827280/rubbic) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55507076/why-does-github-2fa-recovery-codes-fail/55508031#comment120566188_55508031):

> I contacted github and what I ended up doing was creating a new account and they suggested that after six month they can reassign my previous email to the new account.
> But I lost my previous projects and everything in it!
>
> Lesson learned: use text message authentication, it's the easiest and safest option.

[Wally](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6513660/wally) adds in the comments:

> Github replied after a few weeks.
>
> The only thing they could do was to release my email and username from my account.

Comment: Literally, this is the only thing I haven't tried yet! I'll try that and if it gets fixed that way your answer definitely needs to be added to the list of possible solutions! Thank you!

Comment: @Wally I contacted github and what I ended up doing was creating a new account and they suggested that after six month they can reassign my previous email to the new account but I lost my previous projects and everything in it! lesson learned, use text message auth it's the easiest and safest option

Comment: @Rubbic Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Github replied after a few weeks. The only thing they could do was to release my email and username from my account.

Comment: @Wally Thank you for the update. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

It is still possible to push through Git Bash and some other third party tools such as TortoiseGit (if those tools had been installed before you lose your 2FA credentials).

Comment: Please help assist with what can i do to do to gain access to the GitHub account.

Current status:
- I have an email, password and they are correct 
- I have downloaded and kept my GitHub recovery code, but it does not work. No idea why
- I have logged in and still have access to the GitHub Desktop
- I have and still have access to my VS code. So i still can clone or push code to the repo still
- The Github mobile was logged out.

Comment: So the only issue is github mobile then? no idea about that.

Comment: I cant log in on web anymore , or mobile app as it is required 2FA. its like dead lock